# How do I get an instance of BaseHTTPRequestHandler instantiated during request handling inside an action code?

Tags: python, pylons

I need to access the rfile and wfile properties of a request handler instance. AFAIK, such a handler is instantiated by the framework during request lifetime.

**Update**: I found that rfile is accessible through request.environ['wsgi.input']. To access wfile I've do a hack with the additional line in Paste sources, httpserver.py:210:

```
,'wsgi.output': self.wfile
```

But I wonder if there is a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better do like this http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#body-app-iter

In pylons action:

```
 f = response.body_file
 f.write('hey')
```

The response.body_file is only like a file object, but not real stream.
For more details read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#id22

Comment: The problem is that I need to provide this file-like object to the third-party code providing that all written to f data will be immediately transmitted over a connection.

Comment: By wsgi standart you must transmit you data by blocks without delay in transimiting. You can write some itarator for yielding this blocks out .